# In App Purchase cocs2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, in-app-purchase

I am trying to get InApp purchase page working with cocos2d. I am trying to figure out a way to register rootviewcontroller in my app delegate. However, I see that the NavigationRootcontroller is already there and If i replace it with a new RootViewcontroller object my game control stop working.

I guess I'm not able to figure out how to get a RootViewcontroller working with cocos2d without messing up the existing NavigationRootcontroller.

I have gone throw Ray Wendelrich's tutorial- however still not able to connect the dots between cocos2d and RootViewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your inAp purchase buttons to navigation control in cocos2d 2.0

```
  AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  [app.navController.view addSubview:mIndicator];
```

Personally I don't suggest any UI elements from UIKit in OpenGL based application. Use graphical buttons.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Raj. In the example above, does mIndicator override a UIView? If you look at Ray Wenderlich's tutorial - it looks like he is suggesting we override the RootViewController itself. and then in the method viewWillAppear try to connect to apple - [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productsLoaded:) name:kProductsLoadedNotification object:nil];
 
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

Comment: @abhishekmishra, its activity indicator...not used separate UIView..see its cocos2d sprite and cocos2d image buttons. Why you need UIView for inAp purchase? Even if wish to add then what's problem? just add it to app.navController.view.